# How to remove wp panel for users

Tags: admin, custom-write-panel

Hello i have a question , i want to create the whole panel for users by myself and i dont wanna just hide the wordpress panel i dont wanna let users have access to wordpress panel, is that possible , because i know how to hide it:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

but if someone type site/wp-admin he still have access.

Comment: Ahhh, good old WPbeginner with its code full of bad practices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never use `current_user_can` function with roles. You should use only capabilities as params, as Codex clearly states:

> While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is
>   supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce
>   unreliable results.

**So, if we've dealt with that major issue...**

There are 2 things you have to do, if you want to disable wp-admin for subscribers:

### 1. Hide Admin Bar

Admin bar is the dark bar displayed at the top of a page, when user is logged in.

You can hide it using this code:

```
function remove_admin_bar() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( in_array('subscriber', $user->roles) ) {
              show_admin_bar(false);
        }
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
```

### 2. Prevent wp-admin access

```
function restrict_wpadmin_access() {
    if ( ! defined('DOING_AJAX') || ! DOING_AJAX ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( in_array('subscriber', $user->roles) ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/user/' ) );  // <- or wherever you want users to go instead
            die;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_wpadmin_access' );
```

If you want to target different user group, all you need to do is to change this line in both functions above to match your needs:

```
if ( in_array('subscriber', $user->roles) ) {
```

Comment: That works perfect for me , thank you very much !! :)

Comment: @Mariusz Take a look at this plugin too: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/

Comment: Thanks but i dont like plugins , its better to do simple stuff like that by yourself.